# Ошибка компиляции на месте вызова printf()

Tags: c++, строки, вывод

Почему вот это работает,

```
printf("%s", "hello");
```

а вот это нет ?

```
string str = "hello";
printf("%s", str);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы работало?

Comment: Сначала вам надо бы объяснить, почему вы вообще ожидали, что второй вариант будет работать. Откуда вообще возник такой вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Потому что `"%s"` используется для строки в стиле C. `string` таковой, в отличие от `"hello"`, не является,
2. но его функция-член `c_str()` возвращает нужное C-представление своего содержимого.

`string str = "hello";`
`printf("%s", str.c_str());`

*Особое мнение* :) - это издевательство - так перемешивать C и C++. Выберите себе один язык и пользуйтесь им...

Comment: Наверное, стоит добавить, что литерал "hello" имеет другой тип, так что если написать `const char *str = "hello";`, то сработает `printf("%s", str);`

Comment: @Alex Titov,  тоже вариант, но, думаю, именно в варианте, указанным в вопросе, нужно было разобраться автору

Comment: Что только не делается в олимпиадном программировании для ускорения работы программы.

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Ускорять олимпиадную задачу ускорением вывода - это сродни попытки поправить экономическое благосостояние семьи алкоголиков путем экономного потребления спичек... :)

Comment: Не согласен. В задачах часто требуется вывести кучу строк, каждая из которых может быть размером в 1e5 чаров. Даже такая оптимизация может значительно ускорить работу программы.

Comment: На тематических сайтах даже проводят различные исследования в способах быстрого ввода/вывода

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Да каких только исследований не проводят :) Тут, на ruSO, тоже очень часто начинают спрашивать, как бы ускорить ввод или вывод - но каждый раз выясняется, что лучше алгоритм O(N^3) заменить алгоритмом O(N*log N)... Приведите конкретный пример, когда на олимпиадной задаче ввод-вывод оказался настолько критичен - только, само собой, не в случае, когда использован неподходящий алгоритм :) С URL и, желательно, с решениями - когда проходит и не проходит, и вся разница только в выводе...

Comment: Согласен, в большинстве случаев ввод/вывод роли не играет, это делает асимптотика. Но всё же он может вместо решения, работающего за 800 мс сократить до решения на 600, а это даёт больше уверенности. Да, с ходу я не смогу найти такой задачи. Но если бы это не играло вообще никакой роли, то зачем челики на всеросах так пишут?

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Потому что, скорее всего, не понимают, *что* нужно ускорять, а что - нет... И *когда* нужно ускорять. "Все зло - в преждевременной оптимизации" (с) Кнут :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91121/discussion-between-matvey-kiselyov-and-harry).

Comment: Нет, простите, некогда - через 5 минут должен убегать от компьютера...